# symfony2 cannot read property 'fnIsDatatable' of undefined

Tags: symfony, datatables

I'm desperate because I don't find any solution on web for my problem.

I work with easytabs, and on every tab I have a different DataTable with different IDs. On page loading, I've to check, if a DataTable is still there.

On localhost everything works fine, but when i push it on the server I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fnIsDataTable' of undefined

[image: error image]

My Code:

```
if ($.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable('#table-history')) {
    $('#table-history').DataTable().destroy();
}
```

I can't explain why it is working on localhost, and any suggestions like "You've to load the jquery before datatable js file" don't solve this issue.

I hope you have any suggestions or experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help for you. 
As @Eliellel said over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48232068/5813861) ,What you are trying is : trying to destroy datatable before its creation. 
try to replace your function with mine.

```
if ($.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable('#table-history')) {
  var table = $('#table-history').DataTable();
  if(table){
      table.destroy();
  }
}
```